# How to undo a xarray.groupby?

Tags: python-xarray

I want to remove the inter annual daily mean from a time series, after I've done so, I'm left with an additional dimension, "dayofyear" which I can't figure out how to get rid off.

The procedure:

```
data = xr.open_dataset(some_data_set) # dims: lon, lat, time
data -= data.groupby("dayofyear").mean() # dims: dayofyear, lon, lat, time
```

how do I get rid of the "dayofyear" dimension now?

I tried

```
data = data.drop_dims("dayofyear")
```

but that removes the data variables from the object.

Thanks

Comment: I found my error, in my particular case, I can't use `data -= ...` but need to do `data = data.groupby(...) - data.grouby(...).mean()` or reassign `data = data.groupby(...)` first. If there is no general answer to my question above which was motivated by an error on my end, then I'd close my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command `data -= data.groupby(...).mean()` must be changed to

```py
# first option
data = data.groupby(...) - data.groupby(...).mean()
```

```py
# second option
data = data.groupby(...)
data -= data.mean()
```